# Is it possible to create a setup project using final builder

Tags: finalbuilder

What is the exact purpose of final builder,Can i create a setup project using final builder for c#.net project?I Googled the same  and found irrelevant results,Please advise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FinalBuilder is an Automated Build Tool, it's not a setup builder.

It's designed to automate the tasks you typically perform when creating a release, ie - get the source code, build it, invoke the setup builder (like installshield, wix, innosetup), copy the files to a network share or ftp/sftp/ftps server.